# 409 'Conflict' Changing ContentType property of Document Library

Tags: javascript, document-library, sharepoint-rest-api

I have about 600 items in a document library. The library has 9 content types defined in it, which is part of a reorganization to take items out of folders and make it folderless. The library is a copy of the original, and so these files have been uploaded by a move operation.  All files are of the default 'Document' content type standard during item creation typically by uploading.

Other than 'Edit Properties' one-by-one for each item, and the inability to use QuickEdit to change the item 'Content Type' field (not a Column), the one way to change rapidly is REST requests. In the about 60-70 lines of code shown below, the script does the following:

1. It has 3 serial REST requests
2. REST request #1 gets the names and IDs of the Content Types of the doc lib, which are then stored in an array of two-property objects
3. REST request #2 then gets all the items of the list filtered for the default "Document" content type, which is to be changed. It selects on one column, "Level 1" (referring to a top-level folder name representing a categorization that became a content type name), and its value is to be used in doing the item Content-Type field update.
4. REST request is the "POST" request supposed to do the modification. Each item request is processed in a for loop, and I put a timeout on each request of 5 seconds to space out the requests so as not to get server errors about resources.

On the "POST" request (innermost), I am getting 409 (Conflict) response errors not on one item, but the rest of the items, and I haven't figured out what is going on. I am looking at the request object message and it shows this

```
{"error":{"code":"-2130575305, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"The file <filename> has been modified by i:0#.f|membership|<user identity> on 26 Feb 2021 07:46:30 -0800."}}}
```

I am also getting an additional message from a function `'findAjaxError()'` in my script library that seems to indicate success.

```
{"readyState":4,"responseText":"","status":204,"statusText":"No Content"}
```

But when I do a count of items with the 'Document' content type after a request to change only 50 items in a retrieved items list, it seems to have only been reduced by 1 item in count.

I am probably not setting up the headers correctly, or using correct method (not "POST", but "PUT" or other?)

Has anyone tried this?

```
function dataTransformer() {
    RESTrequest({
        url: "https://<server+site path>/_api/web/lists/" + 
                            "getByTitle('<doc lib name>')?$expand=ContentTypes&$select=ContentTypes/Id/StringValue,ContentTypes/Name",
        method: "GET",
        successCallback: (data) => {
            let ListContentTypes = [ ], results = data.d.ContentTypes.results, DocumentContentTypeId;

            for (let result of results) {
                if (result.Name == "Document")
                    DocumentContentTypeId = result.Id.StringValue;
                ListContentTypes.push({
                    name: result.Name,
                    id: result.Id.StringValue
                });
            }
            RESTrequest({
                url: "https://<server+site path>/_api/web/lists/" + 
                            "getByTitle('<doc lib name>')/items?$select=Id,Level_x0020_1,File/Name" + 
                            "&$filter=ContentTypeId eq '" + DocumentContentTypeId + "'" +
                            "&$expand=File",
                method: "GET",
                successCallback: (data) => {
                    let ctype, idx, results = data;

                    for (idx = 0; idx < results.length; idx++) {
                        console.log("count of files to be operated on: " + results.length);
                        for (ctype of ListContentTypes)
                            if (ctype.name == results[idx].Level_x0020_1)
                                break;
                        console.log("modifying file '" + results[idx].File.Name + "'");
                        setTimeout(() => {
                            RESTrequest({
                                setDigest: true,
                                url: "https://<server+site path>/_api/web/lists/" + 
                                        "getByTitle('<doc lib name>')/items(" + results[idx].Id + ")",
                                method: "POST",
                                headers: {
                                    "X-HTTP-METHOD": "MERGE",
                                    "IF-MATCH": "*"
                                },
                                data: formatRESTBody([
                                    ["ListItemEntityTypeFullName", <list item entity type full name> ],
                                    ["ContentTypeId", ctype.id]
                                ]),
                                successCallback: (data, text, reqObj) => {
                                    console.log("response data => " + 
                                        JSON.stringify(data) + 
                                        "\nrequestObj => " +
                                        JSON.stringify(reqObj));
                                },
                                errorCallback: (reqObj) => {
                                    console.log(findAjaxError(reqObj));
                                }
                            });
                        }, 5000);
                    }
                },
                errorCallback: (reqObj) => {
                    console.log(findAjaxError(reqObj));
                }
            });
        },
        errorCallback: (reqObj) => {
            console.log(findAjaxError(reqObj));
        }
    });
}
```